# Google Map not displaying through API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

Map not appearing on page. I am attempting to place a map on the page and then add some markers and eventually a sort of instagram mashup. However, the map is not displaying and I cannot figure out why. I have tried numerous things, to no avail. HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBGrN5DdMYr-o1FGaF2bLF4Ub2VZqIrguA"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src='application.js'></script>


</head>

<body>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="height:500px; width:500px;">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var markers = new Array();


    function initialize(){
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 3,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.9047, 77.0164),
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas') , mapOptions);

    } 
});
```

The map is not displaying. I am not getting any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling your function. You need to call it by adding `initialize();` somewhere after the function. Personally, I would move the function to outside the `.ready()` and only put the call to it there, like this:

```
var markers = new Array();
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.9047, 77.0164),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  initialize(); // call the function on page load
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/yvrr704t/1/